# I need to find a US based repository

Tags: official-repositories

DNS resolves archive.ubuntu.com and us.archive.ubuntu.com to IP addresses registered through RIPE as being in the UK. Am I misunderstanding the "us" country code in this case?

Can someone tell me how to assure that what I download from an Ubuntu repo actually came from servers located in the US?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Since Canonical IIRC is originally a UK company, it's possible they bought a set of IPs that are all now registered as being in the UK, but they can of course use them for any physical locations outside the UK. Test latencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to locate a mirror based in the nation you wish.

Then test the corresponding IP address to confirm that it is in the nation's assigned range.